# MathNet Real number evaluation

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I have the following using MathNet library where child1 is -4.09 and child2 is -4.162.  The result after Expression.Real((double1 - double2)) returns 0.072000000000000064.  It should be 0.072.  Can anyone please help me understand what is going on?

```
private static Expression GetSimplifiedExpression(Expression child1, Expression child2, LaTeXTokenType tokenType)
{
    double double1 = Evaluate.Evaluate(null, child1).RealValue;
    double double2 = Evaluate.Evaluate(null, child2).RealValue;

    return Expression.Real((double1 - double2));
}
```

Comment: This is how floating-point arithmetic works.  There's a whole website devoted to explaining it: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: you can use Decimal...thats a fixed point data type...not as flexible though

Answer (score 0):

First, let's convert decimal to binary:

`-4.09  = -100.00010111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111...`

`-4.162 = -100.00101001011110001101010011111101111100111011011001000101101000...`

Then, subtract those two binaries. The result in binary is:

`0.00010010011011101001011110001101010011111101111100111011011001...`

which is approximately equal to decimal `0.07199999999999999998`.

It is not exactly `0.072000000000000064`, but I think you could get the idea behind it. If you want the exact result, you could cast `double` to `decimal`:

```
var decimal1 = (decimal) double1;
var decimal2 = (decimal) double2;
```